# Why does JavaScript sometimes convert null to empty string and sometimes to "null" string?

Tags: javascript, string, null

I'm studying JavaScript and I'm confused about the following:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = typeof (document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML);
```

It assigns "string" to an HTML element. OK. So then I suppose when I will try to assign some value of different type (not string) it will be converted to string first:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = null; //null will be converted to string first
```

like this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = String(null);
```

HTML element gets en empty value in the first example. But the second example returns "string". Why? This tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp says that String(null) returns "null", but not empty string. As I see it's true only for the second example.

How to understand this confusing conversion behavior of JavaScript? Why doesn't the first example return "string"?

**Edited:**

Now partially I understood it.
JS uses `toString()` but not `String()`. And `toString()` returns empty string for null.
So now my question is: Why `toString()` and `String()` produce different values?

**Edited 2:**

Examples:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = String(null); //returns an empty string 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = null.toString(); //returns "null" string
```

Comment: Regarding your edit, [`ToString()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8) would also yield `"null"`.

Comment: @Ja͢ck But toString() returns empty string in Chrome...

Comment: Which `toString()` are you talking about then?

Comment: I added examples in "Edited 2" above which illustrate the the different behavior

Comment: In Safari I get "TypeError: null is not an object" when I attempt `null.toString()` ... so this is likely to be an implementation detail and shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: `'Hello null'.indexOf(null)` ---> 6

Comment: but `[1,2,3,null,5].join(" ")` --> `'1 2 3  5'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a real convention here; `Element.innerHTML` is a property that tests the given value to determine what to do. In Safari it behaves like this:

```
if (value === null || value === '') {
    // remove all contents
} else {
    // parse string representation of value into the elements contents
}
```

So both `""` (empty string) and `null` are considered the same and the assignment will just remove all contents; I couldn't find conclusive evidence that would suggest other browsers work this way, but it seems very likely that it should be considered an implementation detail that you shouldn't rely upon (see update).

That said, the documented way of clearing an element is by assigning the empty string to this property.

#### Update

I've found this (inconclusive) [email thread](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapi/2007Jun/0008.html) about the subject, highlighting that this behaviour is not standardised:

> For .innerHTML = null Opera and Internet Explorer act as if the literal
> string "null" was used. Firefox acts as if "" was used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Maybe it's true. But I investigated that toString() and String() return different values for null. Probably before assigning a value to html JS uses toString() because it returns empty string for null. I updated my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You wrote:

> ```
> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = String(null); //returns an empty string 
> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = null.toString(); //returns "null" string
> ```

But both assertions are false, I am afraid.

`String(null)` never returns an empty string, rather a primitive of type `string` whose value is "null".

BTW, The form `String(null)` [should *never* be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

`new String(null)`, on the other hand, returns an object, instance of `String` (note the uppercase first letter) whose primitive value (`[[PrimitiveValue]]` internal property) is `"null"`.

`null.toString()` raises an error in every JS engine I know : event though `null` might be considered an object (due to a historical bug), it has no property, therefore no 'method' `toString()` (I quote the 'method' because there are no method in JS, really).

Anyway, to be consistent, you could use this :

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = whateverVariable || '';
```

Should `whateverVariable` be falsy (`null`, `undefined`, `0`, `-0`, `''`, `NaN` or `false`), empty string `''` will be assigned to `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML`.